# Ubuntu 22.04 don't show popup with request of root password

Tags: permissions, popup-ads

Some app (teamviwer) needs root password to change configuration. I have problem, because when I click on button to "ask of root permission" nothing show. [image]

It's the same issue one wayland and xorg.
I have second laptop this the same ubuntu, the same teamviwer and there popup works. I don't know what should check/reconfigure/reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I was found a reason with a workaround, but can't find a permanent solution. Anny suggestion please?!

Problem start after add by me file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/90-silence-steam.conf` whose is a response if STEAM admin popup issue from topic https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/7856#issuecomment-883386818

In file is:

```
└─# cat ~/90-silence-steam.conf                                                                                                                                             130 ⨯
[Stop steam user from prompting for network permissions]
Identity unix-user:xavery
Action org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system
ResultActive no
ResultInactive no
ResultAny no
```

When I rm/rm this file from localization `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/` popups start working

Any idea how fix this permanently and safe this file to fix steam popup?